# What is the vertical separation minima between IFR and VFR?

Tags: air-traffic-control, visual-flight-rules, separation

ICAO Doc 4444, 5.3.2 says

> The vertical separation minimum (VSM) shall be:
>
> a) a nominal 300 m (1 000 ft) below FL 290 and a nominal 600 m (2 000 ft) at or above this level, except as provided for in b) below; and
>
> b) within designated airspace, subject to a regional air navigation agreement: a nominal 300 m (1 000 ft) below FL 410 or a higher level where so prescribed for use under specified conditions, and a nominal 600 m (2 000 ft) at or above this level.

Is Vertical separation minima between IFR and VFR 1000 ft? If yes, then should a VFR flying at VFR cruising level be given climb/descent or vectored to have lateral separation?

**No United States specific answers please**

Comment: ATC will try to provide separation for known VFR, but if the airspace is shared with uncontrolled VFR aircraft, it would be impossible to separate VFR and IFR aircraft.

Answer (score 2):

I admit I am not an expert, but having skimmed through Doc 4444 I see nothing that provides other vertical separation minima applicable only to VFR aircraft. Therefore I must assume that the minima you listed apply equally to IFR and to VFR aircraft, and you are correct that lateral separation must be effected if vertical separation does not exist.

**However**, those minima only apply within that airspace in which VFR aircraft are provided separation services at all. From 5.2.1.1:

> Vertical or horizontal separation shall be provided:
> **a)** between all flights in Class A and B airspaces;
> **b)** between IFR flights in Class C, D and E airspaces;
> **c)** between IFR flights and VFR flights in Class C airspace;
> **d)** between IFR flights and special VFR flights; and
> **e)** between special VFR flights, when so prescribed by the appropriate ATS authority;

See also the Note at 5.10.1.1:

> *Note.— Pursuant to Section 5.2, but subject to certain exceptions stated therein, ATC is required to provide separation between IFR flights in airspace Classes A to E, and between IFR and VFR flights in Classes B and C. ATC is not required to provide separation between VFR flights, except within airspace Class B. Therefore, IFR or VFR flights may constitute essential traffic to IFR traffic, and IFR flights may constitute essential traffic to VFR traffic. However, a VFR flight would not constitute essential traffic to other VFR flights except within Class B airspace.*

Answer (score 2):

When a seperation service is applied those are the vertical seperation standards applied. The only different between IFR and VFR is the class of airspace and if a serperation service is applied.

| Class | Type of Flight | Seperation Provided |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | IFR | All Aircraft |
|  | *VFR not Permitted* |  |
| **B** | IFR | All Aircraft |
|  | VFR | All Aircraft |
| **C** | IFR | IFR from IFR; IFR from VFR |
|  | VFR | VFR from IFR |
| **D** | IFR | IFR from IFR |
|  | VFR | *Nil* |
| **E** | IFR | IFR from IFR |
|  | VFR | *Nil* |
| **F** | IFR | IFR from IFR as far as practical |
|  | VFR | *Nil* |
| **G** | IFR | *Nil* |
|  | VFR | *Nil* |

*Extracted from ICAO Annex 11: Air Traffic Services, Chapter 2, Appendix 4*

The vertical seperation standards are then applied where ever speration is provided to the aircraft.